# django required file field validation

Tags: python, django

Working with django form in which i have two file uploads fields one for artist image and another for event poster, both of these fields are required.

```
class CreateEventStepFirstForm(forms.Form):
    event_title = forms.CharField(required = True, max_length=20, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class' : 'custome-input promote-input', 
        'autocomplete' : 'off',
        'data-empty-message':'This field is required' 
    }))
    ticket_title = forms.CharField(required = True, max_length=225, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class' : 'custome-input promote-input', 
        'autocomplete' : 'off',
        'data-empty-message':'This field is required' 
    }))
    artist_image = forms.FileField(required = True, widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={
        'class' : 'upload-img',
        'data-empty-message':'Please upload artist image, this field is required'
    }))
    event_poster = forms.FileField(required = True, widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={
        'class' : 'upload-img',
        'data-empty-message':'Please upload artist image, this field is required'
    }))
```

Problem is that all fields are validated properly except these two file fields, when i select images for both artist_image and event_poster it don't validate the fields and give "This field is required" error even i select both images.

[image]

Comment: Did you forget to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your `<form>` tag?

Comment: No i have added enctype already in my form

Comment: Is the name of field in html form same as those in forms.py?

Comment: @cutteeth I am only using forms.py to generate html form in html file

Comment: {{ stepFirstForm.artist_image }} and {{ stepFirstForm.event_poster }} these are the two code that i am using in my html file

Comment: Post your view and your template.

Comment: in your views.py how are you processing files? It shoud be something like `stepFirstForm = stepFirstForm(request.POST, request.FILES)`

Comment: @cutteeth Thanks its working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `request.FILES` as follows:

```
form = CreateEventStepFirstForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Comment: Thank you, would you also please tell me that how can we make a field which only accept integer values, means we cannot write string value in it, using forms.py

Comment: You can use `forms.IntegerField`, more details in [IntegerField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#integerfield)

Comment: But for using models.IntegerField i have to use model form right

Comment: Yes I am using forms.IntegerFile, but it allows me to enter string in text field, i want like if we set max_length=20 for any text file then it does not allow us to enter more than 20 characters in field, we can't write into text field more than 20 letters, same i want for integer field

Comment: `forms.IntegerField` might take `max_value` and `min_value` arguments if that's what you need. You might want to try something like this: `forms.IntegerField(min_value=5, max_value=10, widget=forms.NumberInput())`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125995/discussion-between-pankaj-and-ettanany).